# In my virtual environment pip is not working

Tags: python, django, pip

```
(env) PS C:\Users\ZEWDU\Documents\EthLink> pip   
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\ZEWDU\Documents\env\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\ZEWDU\Documents\EthLink\env\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I was working on my django project and when I try to install packages using pip I get the above error.

Not tried anything yet?

Comment: Should install `pip` first in your environment

Comment: I have already installed pip.